# Data is not not getting in ProductDeatils page . Returing an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

When I clicked on any item it is giving me an empty array in product detail page. The first time when I clicked one of the products it was giving me everything on this product id but after some time it showed me an empty array. and showing me this error
ProductDetails.jsx:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images'). I am using here reactjs 18 version, redux-toolkit, and node 16 version. Please help me solve this issue.

```
  -----------------PeoductDetails.jsx ----------------------
  
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
  import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
  import MetaData from '../../more/MetaData'
  import { getSingleProduct, STATUSES } from '../../store/slices/productSlice';
  import Header from '../Home/Header'
  import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
  import loading from "../../assets/loading.svg"
  import Slider from "react-slick";
  import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
  import ShoppingBagOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingBagOutlined';

  const ProductDetails = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const { id } = useParams()
      const { products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product)
      console.log(products);

      const slider = {
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          speed: 3000,
          autoplaySpeed: 6000,
          cssEase: "linear"
      };

      useEffect(() => {

          const fetchProduct = () => {
              const action = getSingleProduct(id?.toString())
              dispatch(action)
          }

          fetchProduct()

      }, [dispatch, id])
      console.log(products.product);

      if (status === STATUSES.LOADING) {
          return (
              <div className="w-full h-[100vh] flex justify-center items-center bg- 
              gray-100">
                   <img src={loading} alt="" className="bg-transparent rounded-full h- 
                   [300px]" />
              </div>
          );
      }
      return (
          <>
                <MetaData title="Product Details" />
                <Header />
                <div className="w-full flex justify-around md:flex-row flex-col">
                    <div>
                        <Slider {...slider}>

                            <div>
                                {products.product.images && 
                                    products.product.images.map((item, i) => (
                                        <img
                                         key={i}
                                         src={item.url}
                                         alt={`${i} Slide`}
                                         className="w-[350px] h-[350px] object-contain"

                                        />
                                  ))}

                          </div>


                      </Slider>
                  </div>

                 <div>
                <h2>{products.product.name}</h2>

                <div>
                    <span>({products.product.numOfReviews})</span>
                </div>

                <h2>₹{products.product.price}</h2>

                <div>
                    <sapn>Quantity</sapn>

                    <div>
                        <button>-</button>
                        <input type="number" />
                        <button>+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>{products.product.stock < 1 ? "OutOfStock" : "InStock"}</p>

                <div>
                    {products.product.description}
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div>
                        <FavoriteBorderIcon />
                        <span>Add to wishlist</span>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <ShoppingBagOutlinedIcon />
                        <span>Add to Cart</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </>
   )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

---------- productSlice.js -------------------------------------

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import * as api from "../api";

export const STATUSES = Object.freeze({
    IDLE: 'idle',
    ERROR: 'error',
    LOADING: 'loading',
});


// Thunk
export const fetchAllProducts = createAsyncThunk("products/getAllProduct", async (_, 
thunkAPI) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.getAllProducts()
    
        return response.data

    }catch(error){
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
    }
})

export const getSingleProduct  = createAsyncThunk("product/getSingleProduct", async 
(id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.getSingleProduct(id)
        console.log(response.data);
        return await response.data

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error.response)
        return rejectWithValue(error.response)
    }
})

const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: "product",
    initialState: {
        products: [],
        status: STATUSES.IDLE,
        message: ""
    },
    reducers: {},

    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchAllProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = STATUSES.LOADING
            })

            .addCase(fetchAllProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.products = action.payload
                state.status = STATUSES.IDLE
            })

            .addCase(fetchAllProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = STATUSES.ERROR
                state.message = action.payload.message
             })

             .addCase(getSingleProduct.pending, (state, action) => {
                 state.status = STATUSES.LOADING
              })

             .addCase(getSingleProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                 state.products = action.payload
                 state.status = STATUSES.IDLE
        
              })

            .addCase(getSingleProduct.rejected, (state, action) => {
                 state.status = STATUSES.ERROR
                 state.message = action.payload.message
              })
    }
})

export default productSlice.reducer
```

----------------------- store.js ----------------------

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import productSlice from "./slices/productSlice";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        product: productSlice
    }
})
```

export default store

------- api.js ----------------

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})


export const getAllProducts = async () => await API.get("/api/v2/products")

export const getSingleProduct = async (id) => await API.get(`/api/v2/products/${id}`)
```

------- Error ---

```
 ProductDetails.jsx:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined 
 (reading 'images')
 at ProductDetails (ProductDetails.jsx:56:1)
 at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
 at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
 at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
 at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
 at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
 at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
 at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
 at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
 at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Home screen
[image]

Comment: did you check the network tab, if your api is returning data?

Comment: In Home Screen I am getting 200 But when I clicked on any item images I am not getting anything in network tab.

Comment: can you console.log in the asyncthunk and check if it is reaching or not(both in try and catch block). also please ensure no filter is on in the network tab

Comment: It is giving me undefined and an empty array

Comment: console.log  before the api call, as you told nothing in network tab-> that means api call is not happening correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the products array is empty, you need a create a different state slice for single product, like `currentProduct`. Remember empty array returns `true` so products will return true and thus accessing any property on empty array will give errors. You can check if the array is empty by `products.length > 0` or `_.isEmpty()` from `lodash`

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

in ProductDetails.jsx

```
  useEffect(() => {

      const fetchProduct = () => {
          //const action = getSingleProduct(id?.toString()) // remove
          const action = getSingleProduct(id) // use

          dispatch(action)
      }

      fetchProduct()

  }, [dispatch, id])
```